# How to get wdio running through IntelliJ run/debug configurations?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, cucumber

I can run the tests from the command line using

```
>  ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js
```

But if I try to run this from IntelliJ's run/debug configuration I get various different errors.

> Featurefile or directory:      /path_to_my_feature_file/myfeature.feature 
>   Cucumber.js arguments:      wdio.conf.js
>  
>   Executable path:                       /path_to_my_project/node_modules/.bin/wdio

gives me

> more than one config file specified

If I remove the Cucumber Arguments, it just runs indefinitely.  If I stop it running I get the error

> Failed loading configuration file

It looks like there's some kind of issue with loading the config file, but I don't know how to fix it.  Any suggestions?  wdio.conf.js exists and is in the project root.

Comment: what run configuration do you use? Please try Node.js - see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieFVT.png

Comment: thanks lena.  I've been using cucumber.js.  I tried Node.js as in your image - it doesn't error, but the tests don't seem to run either - they just don't do anything, looks like they start but don't stop, don't output anything.

Comment: known issue, please see my answer for a workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebStorm doesn't provide any special support for `wdio` test runner. But you can still run/debug the tests using **Node.js** run configuration like the following:

[image]

But this doesn't work out of the box due to problems related to using non-tty environment (Node.js run console in IDEA is non-tty). As a workaround, please try commenting out `if (process.stdin.isTTY)` and `else` branch in `node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\cli.js`:

```
//if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
    launch();
/*
} else {
   var stdinData = '';
    /!*
     * get a list of spec files to run from stdin, overriding any other
     * configuration suite or specs.
     *!/
    var stdin = process.openStdin();
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', function (data) {
        stdinData += data;
    });
    stdin.on('end', function () {
        if (stdinData.length > 0) {
            args['specs'] = stdinData.trim().split(/\r?\n/);
        }
        launch();
    });
}*/
```

see [WEB-31745](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31745)

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm using IntellJ IDEA and have setup configuration as you mentioned it above, but I get this error when clicking on debug button (in my next comment). Can you help with that? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `C:\WORK\IntelliJ_IDEA\project\node_modules\.bin\wdio:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: you are passing a bash script as `.js` file to Node.js; change *Javascript file* path in your run configuration from `node_modules\.bin\wdio` to `node_modules\webdriverio\bin\wdio `

Answer (score 5):

To get this to work with webdriverio v5 and higher you need to set in the debug configurations screen above

the path to the runner as the javascript file to execute:

node_modules@wdio\cli\bin\wdio.js

and the conf file as the application parameters:

wdio.conf.js