# How to use intellij idea debugger with webdriverIO?

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs, wdio-v5

I have an issue on wdio test runner. I have set it up in IntelliJ Idea as described here: [How to get wdio running through IntelliJ run/debug configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724279/how-to-get-wdio-running-through-intellij-run-debug-configurations/55222974#55222974?newreg=65b5f9ee800147789d007da2042a9019) But, when I try to debug, nothing happens. The test is not stopping on a breakpoint, it just continues on running. Please help me to set up the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

This config works for me. Breakpoints work

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have same configs, I would like to ask you what language do you use, I have this problem with TypeScript

Comment: @Alex JavaScript

Comment: For me it’s not working with TypeScript, may be you know what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I have debugging works (with Angular, I thought it would be the same with Node) in Intellij with the following steps:

1. Run `npm run start` to start your server with debug.
   [image: Image1]
2. Run your test config with debug too.
   [image: Image2]
3. Now you can set breakpoints

Sorry for inconvenient pictures, I'm not allowed to directly post picture yet.